Passing multiple templated functions and their arguments at once
I want to make a class that will take multiple functions (function pointers, lambdas, classes with operator(), etc), save them in a tuple, and then call all of them with passed arguments (assuming that each function is callable with them). I also want to put it under templated interface so that the caller only knows about required arguments and return types of functions (which will be required only for bool specialization). Here's what I approximately am trying to achieve (and full version):
template<typename Ret, typename... Args>
class MultiCall
{
public:
    virtual void operator()(Args... args_) = 0;
};

template<typename Ret, typename... Args, typename... Fs>
class MultiCallImpl : public MultiCall<Ret, Args...>
{
public:
    MultiCallImpl(Fs... fs_) :
        m_funcs(fs_...)
    {
    }

    virtual void operator()(Args... args_) override
    {
        ((std::get<Fs>(m_funcs)(args_...)), ...);
    }

private:
    std::tuple<Fs...> m_funcs;
};

If I remove both Ret and Args, it compiles fine, but with any of them it can't deduce types of functions and it complains about Args being in the middle of variadic template, although, as far as I know, its possible to put multiple parameter packs in the template if they can be automatically deduced. Is it possible to fix this code to achieve what I want?

How about std::vector/std::array of std::function<Ret(Args...)>?

@Jarod42 unless I'm using std::function wrong, it seems to be more than twice slower at calls, code

Even more if we consider the time to create an object, example

It is generally illegal for pack like that ...Args not to be last. There are few exceptions and your code is not putting any effort into attempting to be such an exception.

When using std::array and optimization flag 34ms versus 38ms Demo

But indeed 1,5 slower with quick-bench

I didnt expect such a big difference with O2. I think array is the best compromise, I can hide everything except arguments and return type and its still not that much slower. I guess quick bench shows worse results because of gcc version difference, its around 1.3 times with clang. I'll probably use arrays then, thanks

If you change signature of the template, you might do
template<typename Sig, typename... Fns>
class MultiCall;

template<typename Ret, typename... Args, typename... Fs>
class MultiCall<Ret(Args...), Fs...>
{
public:
    MultiCall(Fs... fs_) : m_funcs(fs_...) {}

    auto operator()(Args... args) const
    {
        return std::apply([&](auto...fs) {
            if constexpr (std::is_same_v<Ret, void>) {
                (fs(args...), ...);
            } else {
                return std::make_tuple(fs(args...)...);
            }
        }, m_funcs);
    }

private:
    std::tuple<Fs...> m_funcs;
};

// No partial CTAD, so make_*
template <typename Sig, typename... Fs>
MultiCall<Sig, Fs...> make_multiCall(Fs... fs)
{
    return {fs...};
}

Note: You can even add constraint requires (std::is_invocable_r_v<Ret, Fs, Args...> && ...)
with usage
auto mc = make_multiCall<void()>(doNothing, [](){std::cout << "More text\n";});

Demo

could return a std::array<Ret, sizeof...(Fs)>, rather than a tuple

@Caleth: depends if we want to convert return type (which might be better indeed IMO) (as currently I kept them Demo
